# It is false that Arg$(z)$ is harmonic in every domain that does not contain the origin

Tags: complex-analysis

I'm asked to show that Arg$(z)$ being harmonic in every domain that does not contain the origin is *false.*

I understand how to show that Arg$(z)$ is harmonic in every domain that does not contain the negative half-line $(-\infty,0]$, Arg not even being defined at $z=0.$

Arg$(z)$ is the imaginary part of $\text{Log}(z)= \ln|z|+i\cdot \text{Arg}(z)$ for domain $D:=\{|z|>0, -\pi < \text{Arg}(z) < \pi\}$

and since $\frac{d}{dz}[\text{Log}(z)] = \frac{1}{z}$ for domain $D:=\{|z|>0, -\pi < \text{Arg}(z) < \pi\}$

by the Theorem: *If a function $f(z)=u(x,y)+iv(x,y)$ is analytic in a domain $D$, then its component functions $u$ and $v$ are harmonic in $D$*

Given $f(z) = \text{Log}(z)= \ln|z|+i\cdot \text{Arg}(z)$ where $f$ is analytic in $D$, since $v = \text{Arg}(z)$, $\text{Arg}(z)$ is harmonic in $D$.

How do I show $\text{Arg}(z)$ is not harmonic on $(-\infty,0)$?

I understand that $\text{Arg}(z)= \begin{cases} \arctan(y/x), && x>0 \\ \arctan(y/x) +\pi, && x<0, y\geq 0 \\ \arctan(y/x) -\pi, && x<0, y<0\\ \frac{\pi}{2}, && x=0,y>0 \\ -\frac{\pi}{2}, && x=0,y<0 \\ \text{undefined}, && x=0,y=0\end{cases}$ is not continuous on the negative half-line, which implies it is not differentiable on the negative half-line, so I have an intuition that maybe this is why.

Comment: it is not even continuous as if you approach the negative line from below you get $-\pi$ and from above $\pi$

Comment: Take the domain $\mathbb{C} \setminus \{0 \}$.

Comment: @Conrad, I understand those details precisely given the last mention in my post, I’m having trouble understanding the sequence of ideas that lead to: discontinuous implies not harmonic, if such a sequence is indeed possible, if not, a counterexample would be great thanks!

Comment: @copper.hat I’m not quite sure I follow?

Comment: A harmonic function on an open set is real analytic by general theory - I am curious how you define harmonicity without having at least some differentiability properties that allow the laplacian to be computed (it can be done of course but not sure how you define harmonicity)

Comment: @Conrad The book says: A real-valued function $H$ of two real variables $x$ and $y$ is said to be harmonic in a given domain of the $xy$ plane if, throughout that domain, it has continuous partial derivatives of the first and second order and satisfies the partial differential equation $H_{xx}(x,y)+H_{yy}(x,y) = 0$...

Comment: @Conrad I don't see how the first-order or second-order partial derivatives have anything to do with $f'(z)$ not existing on the negative real line, I have a theorem that says that if $f'(z_0)$ does not exist then either the Cauchy-Riemann equations are not satisfied at $z_0$ or the first order partial derivatives with respect to $x$ and $y$ do not exist, where $f(z) = u(x,y) + iv(x,y)$

Comment: Differentiability implies continuity so a discontinuous function cannot have a derivative; harmonic functions are continuous and more (real analytic); if you prove that a function is not continuous at a point, it cannot be harmonic on a neighborhood of the point

Comment: @Conrad, how do I know that harmonic functions are continuous? I know that the first and second order partial derivatives with respect to x,y exist and are continuous, does this imply if f(x,y) is harmonic then it has a derivative there which would then imply continuous? The tool I have to show that a derivative exists somewhere relies on the first order partial derivatives with respect to x,y existing and the Cauchy-Riemann equations holding. Sure, if harmonic then the first order partial derivatives exist, but what about the Cauchy-Riemann equations?

Comment: Do you know about differentiability if function in several variables? Continuous partial derivatives mean a function is differentiable (in the real sense so nothing to do with Cauchy -Riemann just calculus 3) so continuous; harmonic function are of course much more than continuous or twice differentiable but that requires some work; continuity though at least in the usual definition is more or less given

Comment: @Conrad, Oh ok! I was curious if you were referring to Cal 3 or not, I was trying to find the answer strictly using my Complex Variables text, but yes that makes sense!

Comment: @Conrad, how can you show that if a function is not continuous at a point, it cannot be harmonic on a neighborhood of the point, Arg$(z)$ is not continuous on $(-\infty,0]$, if it were not harmonic on a neighborhood of each point on the negative real line, how can it be harmonic on $\mathbb{C}\setminus (\infty,0]$?